# Firefox Gtk-CRITICAL error

Tags: 12.10, firefox, gtk

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and I usually start firefox by the command line and after an upgrade I noticed that I am getting these errors.  I don't see many posts about them from others, so I have very little to go by as far as to how to fix them. Has anyone else seen this error, and if so what did you do to fix it?

```
gserver@gserver:~$ firefox

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(firefox:22346): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed
```

How can I fix/adjust my GTK_SETTINGS?

TIA

Matt

Comment: I needed to add GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc to ~/.bashrc.  I am still getting errors so there are probably more environmental variables missing.

Comment: Anybody else experience this problem?

Answer (score 0):

See if the line

> include "/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"

is located in your `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file, and try removing it. This worked for me. The only line now in my `~/.gtkrc-2.0` is

> gtk-theme-name="oxygen-gtk"

Comment: No the only include files that I see are include "xfce.rc", include "menubar.rc", and  include "chrome.rc"